# Error when overlaying two images in OpenCV and or PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

I've tried overlaying two images in openCV both in openCV and in PIL, but to no avail. I'm using a `1000x1000x3` array of `np.zeros` for the background (aka, a black background) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvymf.jpg) random image of my monitor, but I really can't get it to work for some reason unbeknownst to me.

Trying with OpenCV only: ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7PID.jpg)(if you pay attention, you can see a couple of weird lines and dots in the middle))

```
base_temp = np.zeros((1000,1000,3))
foreground_temp = cv2.imread('exampleImageThatILinkedAbove.png')

base_temp[offset_y:offset_y+foreground_temp.shape[0], offset_x:offset_x+foreground_temp.shape[1]] = foreground_temp
```

Trying with PIL: (The result is literally the same as the OpenCV version)

```
base_temp = cv2.convertScaleAbs(self.base)   #Convert to uint8 for cvtColor
base_temp = cv2.cvtColor(base_temp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)   #PIL uses RGB and OpenCV uses BGR
base_temp = Image.fromarray(base_temp)    #Convert to PIL Image
foreground_temp = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.convertScaleAbs(self.last_img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
foreground_temp = Image.fromarray(foreground_temp)
base_temp.paste(foreground_temp, offset)
```

I'm using python3.5 and and OpenCV3.4 on Windows 10, if that's any help.

I'd *like* to avoid any solutions that require saving the cv2 images and then reloading them in another module to convert them but if it's unavoidable that's okay too. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And what are you expecting to get as a result image?

Comment: @DmitriiZ. `foreground_temp` right in the middle of `base_temp` -- or at least pasted in the middle of `base_temp` according to the offset provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the type of `base_temp`, you will see it is `float64` and that is going to cause you problems when you try to save it as a JPEG which expects unsigned 8-bit values.

So the solution is to create your `base_temp` image with the correct type:

```
base_temp = np.zeros((1000,1000,3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

The complete code and result look like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Make black background - not square, so it shows up problems with swapped dimensions
base_temp=np.zeros((768,1024,3),dtype=np.uint8)
foreground_temp=cv2.imread('monitor.png')

# Paste with different x and y offsets so it is clear when indices are swapped
offset_y=80
offset_x=40
base_temp[offset_y:offset_y+foreground_temp.shape[0], offset_x:offset_x+foreground_temp.shape[1]] = foreground_temp

Image.fromarray(base_temp).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I do that in the line `cv2.convertScaleAbs` in the PIL example -- that's why it's there.

Comment: I was referring to your first example.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I ended up getting a resulting image very similar to the results I linked above -- a black screen with a weird line and a couple stray pixels. I'm honestly stumped at this point.

Comment: I can only suspect your installation is *"unhappy"* and that you reinstall. My code is straight-up, as shown and tested to work.

Comment: Well, damn. I tried this on ubuntu and it worked just fine, so I'll accept your answer. Any reason why the installation could have ended up like this, even though it's still relatively "fresh"?